# Vue.js: How can I conditionally include an SCSS?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, lazy-loading, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a Vue.js SPA which can have **default styling** or a **customised styling**.

The **default styling** is built into the Vue.js app, using an `import` statement on a main SCSS file:

`import '/assets/scss/main.scss';`

The **custom styling** are available as an already compiled CSS file on a CDN.

During the application bootstrap, we make a request to the backend to check if we need to fetch a custom CSS, or if we can use the default styles.

As of now, the default styles are always imported and the custom styles override the styles already defined. Obviously this is not ideal on a performance point of view.

Is it possible to import the default SCSS only if the custom CSS could not be found?

Comment: You can compile your SCSS to CSS and then host it on the CDN along the custom styles - then if you can not load the custom styles you will load the default CSS.

Comment: Yes, that would work too although it requires me to adapt the toolchain a little. Still, I'd be interested to know if conditionally importing it could work...

Comment: A static import can not be conditional - but a dynamic one could be, just like you are lazy-loading routes/components.